# How do I write off an invoice in GnuCash?

Tags: gnucash, writeoffs

I've tried 3 ways

- pay the invoice and then record a debit offsetting the payment. Messes up the totals but the balance is the same.
- pay the invoice and then apply a 100% refund in the payment screen. This doesn't seem to work as the invoice is not marked as pay.
- us a credit note. I've created a new invoice then marked it as a credit note type. I've hit pay on the invoice that needs to be written off and selected the credit note. It doesn't apply the credit note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the steps in the gnucash mailing list that worked well for me.

1. New Invoice from the menu
2. Select credit note as the type of invoice
3. Fill out the invoice the same way as the original invoice was created

Then from

http://gnucash.1415818.n4.nabble.com/GNUCash-Credit-Notes-td4685718.html

Apply the credit note by using business > customer > process payment window rather than by trying to use the pay button when the invoice is displayed

1. open the Process Payment Window
2. Select the proper customer
3. Select both invoice and credit note
4. If invoice and credit note are not offsetting each other exactly, adjust
   the payment or refund amount to reflect whether you have also paid the
   remaining amount or not (if you have paid the remaining amount, continue to
   select the account you used for that payment, otherwise the the payment/refund
   fields to 0)
5. Hit ok.